# how to place subview anywhere on screen, 'Docking Views'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

On iOS, what's a way to be able to place a view, like a subView, anywhere on screen (Main View)? I'm providing an interface to users where they can place it anywhere they want (Docking Views) ?

Comment: Set the frame of that subview and add it to superview like: [self.view addSubview: yourSubview];

Comment: i want to drag and drop the subview anywhere in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a pan gesture recognizer (UIPanGestureRecognizer) instead of using touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded. It's much easier and cleaner.

Do a search on "Touches" in the Xcode docs and look for a sample application with that name. There are 2 projects included - one using gesture recognizers, and the other using touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded.

It shows exactly what you need to do in order to drag a view around on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: i want to drag and drop the subview anywhere in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two steps:

1). `yourSubView.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset,yOffset,50,50);`

2). `[self.view addSubview:yourSubView];`

**DRAG AND DROP:**

If u want to drag and drag the subviews u can make use of `touchmethods:` to get the current x and y coordinates and fill them in the frame dynamically.

LIKE:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
    yourSubview.frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Define x,y,w,h;

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
```